# Pandas - Groupby + Shift not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a df that I'm trying to perform a `groupby` and `shift` on. However, the output isn't what I want.

I want to shift the "next" `DueDate` to the previous dates. So if the current `DueDate` is 1/1, and the next `DueDate` is 6/30, then insert a new column where the `NextDueDate` is 6/30 for all rows where `DueDate==1/1`. Then when the current `DueDate` is 6/30, then insert the next `DueDate` for all rows where `DueDate==6/30`.

```
Original df
ID Document Date  DueDate
1  ABC      1/31  1/1  
1  ABC      2/28  1/1  
1  ABC      3/31  1/1  
1  ABC      4/30  6/30 
1  ABC      5/31  6/30 
1  ABC      6/30  7/31 
1  ABC      7/31  7/31 
1  ABC      8/31  9/30

Desired output df
ID Document Date  DueDate NextDueDate
1  ABC      1/31  1/1     6/30
1  ABC      2/28  1/1     6/30
1  ABC      3/31  1/1     6/30
1  ABC      4/30  6/30    7/31
1  ABC      5/31  6/30    7/31
1  ABC      6/30  7/31    9/30
1  ABC      7/31  7/31    9/30
1  ABC      8/31  9/30    10/31
```

I've many variations along the lines of `df['NextDueDate'] = df.groupby(['ID','Document'])['DueDate'].shift(-1)` but it doesn't quite get me where I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function `f` to perform replacement based on shifted dates -

```
def f(x):
     i = x.drop_duplicates()
     j = i.shift(-1).fillna('10/30')

     return x.map(dict(zip(i, j)))
```

Now, call this function inside a `groupby` + `apply` on `ID` and `Document` -

```
df['NextDueDate'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Document']).DueDate.apply(f)
df

   ID Document  Date DueDate NextDueDate
0   1      ABC  1/31     1/1        6/30
1   1      ABC  2/28     1/1        6/30
2   1      ABC  3/31     1/1        6/30
3   1      ABC  4/30    6/30        7/31
4   1      ABC  5/31    6/30        7/31
5   1      ABC  6/30    7/31        9/30
6   1      ABC  7/31    7/31        9/30
7   1      ABC  8/31    9/30       10/30
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
s=df.groupby('DueDate',as_index=False).size().to_frame('number').reset_index()
s.DueDate=s.DueDate.shift(-1).fillna('10/31')
s
Out[251]: 
  DueDate  number
0    6/30       3
1    7/31       2
2    9/30       2
3   10/31       1
s.DueDate.repeat(s.number)
Out[252]: 
0     6/30
0     6/30
0     6/30
1     7/31
1     7/31
2     9/30
2     9/30
3    10/31
Name: DueDate, dtype: object
df['Nextduedate']=s.DueDate.repeat(s.number).values
df
Out[254]: 
   ID Document  Date DueDate Nextduedate
0   1      ABC  1/31     1/1        6/30
1   1      ABC  2/28     1/1        6/30
2   1      ABC  3/31     1/1        6/30
3   1      ABC  4/30    6/30        7/31
4   1      ABC  5/31    6/30        7/31
5   1      ABC  6/30    7/31        9/30
6   1      ABC  7/31    7/31        9/30
7   1      ABC  8/31    9/30       10/31
```

If you have multiple group :

```
l=[]
for _, df1 in df.groupby(["ID", "Document"]):
    s = df1.groupby('DueDate', as_index=False).size().to_frame('number').reset_index()
    s.DueDate = s.DueDate.shift(-1).fillna('10/31')
    df1['Nextduedate'] = s.DueDate.repeat(s.number).values
    l.append(df1)



New_df=pd.concat(l)
```

Comment: If he is operating on a dataframe that has multiple `ID` and `Document` categories wouldn't you have to `groupby(["ID","Document","DueDate"])` to get a generalizable outcome?

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: The code worked until the last part. I get a value error that the length of values does not match length of index.

Comment: @WaltReed did you fillna ?

Comment: @WaltReed Then you need look at your sample data , wehther it can reproduce your problem or not , base on the your sample data, I can not reproduce the problem ...sry

Comment: Came up with something a little different.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha I see:-)